# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded even after increasing maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

I am developer a winform application with WCF service. There are certain forms which display 100-200 rows in a grid. For such cases it fails to show any data and gives this error :

[image]

I have gone through many questions on SO related to this issue. And I tried most of them. But this no luck.

I have changed my application's app.config to look like this :(**UPDATED**)

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://internaladmin.iifl.in/NBFCLAS/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC"
            contract="NbfcService.INBFC" name="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC" />
    </client>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC" closeTimeout="00:59:00"
        openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>      
</system.serviceModel>
```

But it still does not work. I face no issues while my friend to whom I have given the same EXE file is facing such issues.

Note: there is no binding section in WCF service's webconfig.

**Webconfig of WCF:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC" closeTimeout="00:59:00"
        openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service name="NbfcService.INBFC">
    <endpoint
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="NbfcService.INBFC"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: have you implemented DatacontractSerilizer in your WCF web.config file like <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>

Comment: @DhavalPatel no not really. I have updated my question with the webcofig code

Comment: you should have to introduce endpoint and also endpoint behavior and in it you can set the all size related property

Comment: In WCF? (I am new to WCF etc)

Comment: yes you have to search how to configure end point in WCF once you configured it you have to set same size related setting what you have done at winform app.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the maxReceivedMessageSize on the client 'and' on the server. In your case you need to change the binding on the server as well as you did on the client.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC" closeTimeout="00:59:00"
        openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service name="<My service name>">
    <endpoint 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="<my contract name>"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC" />
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: this goes where? In my WCF webconfig?

Comment: In you service side configuration. Web.Config would be nice.

Comment: do i need to give entire setup of the project to my friend or or just replacing exe would work?

Comment: If you only change server config you do not need to do a new installation on a client computer.